# Arrayformula Running Total with multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I've got the following task to solve, but I can't wrap my head around it.

There are a couple of numbers for different years. I would like to have a running total sum of all columns (= range C:I) in column J. I can do that with a formula in every cell of J - however I need to achieve it with a single arrayformula in J2.

[image: Arrayformula Running Total with multiple columns]

What i figured after a lot of research are 2 steps:

1. replace empty cells with 0s, since arrayformulas obviously have some problems with empty cells
2. make a sum of each row

For step 1 the formula is: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(C2:I15),0,C2:I15))` which gives me back a temporary array like:

[image: temporary array]

As this is a 15x7 array, I need something like a 7x1 array to multiply with in order to get a 15x1 array.

That formula would be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C1:I1)^0))`

[image: helper arry]

So in the end my formula so far look like: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(ISBLANK(C2:I15),0,C2:I15),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C1:I1)^0)))`

And this results in a 15x1 array that gives me the sum per row, but not a total running sum of all rows.

[image]

This is where I am stuck - any help and ideas are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: added a shared version for you to fiddle: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cqNEsWHqBaHdDrMY8x4DUKpEkYprRZ8AibEe7d0knPY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so you want to perform running total for each column of C:I range and then sum each row into one single column **OR** you want to sum each row in range C:I and then perform running total to end up with one column ???

Comment: I want to achieve a running total of the range C:I (see first screenshot). So each row the running total should increase. I added a shared sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(M2:M)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(M2:M)))*
 MMULT(C2:I*1; ROW(A1:A7)^0)); SIGN(MMULT(C2:I*1; ROW(A1:A7)^0))^0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: BONUS: added the option to manipulate certain rows (e.g. multiply certain rows with a factor)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work too:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";;SUMIF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(C2:I);COLUMNS(C2:I));"<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(C2:I);1;COLUMNS(C2:I);COLUMNS(C2:I));C2:I)))
```

Comment: genius use of sequence() function. really nice idea!