# Arrayformula for total in simple cashbook

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to create a simple `arrayformula` to keep a running tally in a cashbook. Pretty simple but got me stumped. Heres a basic table:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IN | OUT | TOTAL |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 10 |  | 10 |
| 4 |  | 1 | 9 |
| 5 | 7 |  | 16 |
| 6 | 5 |  | 21 |
| 7 |  | 4 | 17 |

So for example to generate the total in Cell C3 I use the formula `offset(C3,-1,0)-B3+A3` but I thought I would then just be able to wrap it in `arrayformula` so it became `arrayformula(offset(C3:C,-1,0)-B3:B+A3:A)` but it errors and needs an extra row which just goes on endlessly.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

- Use two running totals: of `IN` and `OUT` and subtract `OUT` from `IN`
- Classic arrayformula solution to create a running total is to use SUMIF with a variable string(relative to the `range` argument) as a `criterion`

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A2:A7),"<="&ROW(A2:A7),A2:A7)-SUMIF(ROW(A2:A7),"<="&ROW(A2:A7),B2:B7))
  ```
- Open range version:

  ```
  =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A)-SUMIF(ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A),B2:B)),ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A<>""),ROW(A2:A))),1)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")+(B2:B<>""),
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*IF(A2:A="", -B2:B, A2:A)), 
 SIGN(IF(A2:A="", -B2:B, A2:A))^0), ))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A<>"")+(B2:B<>""),
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*
 IF(A2:A="", A2:A-B2:B, A2:A-B2:B)), 
 SIGN(IF(A2:A="", B2:B, A2:A))^0), ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A))))<=
 TRANSPOSE( ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A))))))*
 (INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A)))-
  INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A))))), 
 SEQUENCE(MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A))-1)^0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I tried @player0 method and got an error about array to big. And for some reason @TheMaster version just got stuck on the progress bar. Anyway found this over on the google help forum

`=ArrayFormula(if(len(A4:A),(SUMIF(ROW(D4:D),"<="&ROW(D4:D),D4:D)+SUMIF(ROW(C4:C),"<="&ROW(C4:C),C4:C)),))`

And seems to work (I have a date in A4:A now). But please let me know if you can see any potential issues

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: My solution works if you copy paste your table in the question to A1 in a, new sheet. You might have to adjust the range if your  data structure is different from what is shown

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
I see that the answer I've adapted from @MattKing, is very similar to @TheMaster's earlier answer, just a variation on how we force the arrayformula to cycle through the cells.

**Answer:**
In addition to player0's solution, I found [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811986/arrayformula-running-total-with-multiple-columns) (where player0 also had the answer!), and adapted a formula answer by @MattKing.  Try the following in C1.

```
={"Total";
ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A),1),"<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A),1,1,1),A2:A) -
             SUMIF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B),1),"<="&SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B),1,1,1),B2:B) )}
```

Since it was originally designed to sum multiple columns, I'm not sure if I've reduced it as much as might be possible, for your single column implementation.